# scp stalls at 2112KB

Tags: networking, server, upgrade, scp

After upgrading an Ubuntu server from 12.04 to 14.04, I am now unable to send (larger) files by `scp`. Also, `bzr` updates and commits to and from the server are unreliable, presumably if the total data transfer exceeds [600kb](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=161898#c6).

I am experiencing the same issue as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985008/sending-a-large-file-with-scp-to-a-certain-server-stalls-at-exactly-2112-kb) (linked from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625000/scp-stalled-while-copying-large-files)).

None of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985008/sending-a-large-file-with-scp-to-a-certain-server-stalls-at-exactly-2112-kb?answertab=votes#tab-top) provided for [either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20625000/scp-stalled-while-copying-large-files?answertab=votes#tab-top) question has resolved the problem.

Neither [this](http://linuxsecure.blogspot.com.es/2008/05/scp-stalled-through-firewall-ssh-no.html) list of solutions, nor this [popular](https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=161898#c6) list of work-arounds, has worked.

Also, 14.04 is not running the 2.4 or 2.6 Kernel anymore.

Finally, I am [unable](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726154/restrictions-when-updating-lts-to-normal) to upgrade the server until 16.04.1 is released.

(**Edit:** After some time, the server has successfully upgraded to 15.10, but the problem persists.)

Suggestions?

EDIT: In response to a comment below, the verbose `scp` log is [here](http://pastebin.com/YBCJ6e8z):

```
$ scp -v test.7z user@host.com:/tmp
Executing: program /usr/bin/ssh host host.com, user user, command scp -v -t /tmp
OpenSSH_6.6.1, OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014
debug1: Reading configuration data /home/user/.ssh/config
debug1: /home/user/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for host.com
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to host.com [xx.yy.zz.aa] port bb.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: identity file /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1p1 Ubuntu-2ubuntu2.4 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA xx:yy:zz...
debug1: Host '[host.com]:bb' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/user/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Next authentication method: password
user@host.com's password: 
debug1: Authentication succeeded (password).
Authenticated to host.com ([xx.yy.zz.aa]:bb).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_ZA.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: scp -v -t /tmp
Sending file modes: C0664 3367893 test.7z
Sink: C0664 3367893 test.7z
test.7z                    64% 2112KB 536.8KB/s - stalled
```

**EDIT:** Transfer (with speed limit) under 15.10. I've always has `ssh` `keepalive` set.

```
Sending file modes: C0775 4243669 test.jar
test.jar   0%    0     0.0KB/s   --:-- ETA
Sink: C0775 4243669 test.jar
test.jar  23%  976KB  16.2KB/s   03:15 ETA
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
test.jar 46% 1936KB  16.0KB/s   02:18 ETA
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
test.jar 50% 2112KB   0.0KB/s - stalled -
debug1:  client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype keepalive@openssh.com reply 1
test.jar 50% 2112KB   0.0KB/s - stalled -
```

Comment: What does adding the `-v` (Verbose) option to your failing `scp` command show?

Comment: I added that, but can't recall anything of interest.

Comment: Please Edit your question and show us (with correct formatting) the copy-and-paste (not screenshot)  from the `scp -v ...` command to the prompt after the failure. Just because it has nothing of interest  to you does not mean that we can't get info from it.

Comment: @waltinator: Done.

Comment: I've added a second log after upgrading to Ubuntu 15.10. In this case, I implemented a rate-limit on the transfer. Without the limit, the transfer jumps to 50% (2112kb) and stalls.

Comment: This problem still persists after a fresh install of Ubuntu 15.10 64-bit server. Incoming transfers stall at 2112kb, the same value as found by others as linked in the question.

Comment: The `mtu` was 1500 by default, which I changed to 1492 after running `tracepath` and `traceroute`. This did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After extensive testing and trying various solutions, which I found by searching for "scp stall" and "scp 2112kb", etc., none of which solved the problem, I considered that the problem could be hardware related, despite the fact that only `scp` transfers were stalling (all other network connectivity and downloads were unaffected).

I swapped out the router for a different (much older) model (different brand as well, I think), and this appears to have solved the problem.